# Implementing a permutation invariant neural network using Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a permutation invariant neural network as mentioned in the article:

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/8078-a-likelihood-free-inference-framework-for-population-genetic-data-using-exchangeable-neural-networks.pdf

The network is explained page 4 and its illustration is on page 6(Figure 1). I have a dataset just like they do. So I have a 1000 2D binary matrices and shape of each 2D matrix is 208 X 5000 and for each 2D matrix I have a corresponding distance vector whose value ranges between 0 and 1. The length of vector is 5000 as well. Each row in the binary matrix corresponds to an individual.

The way I understand this article is that this network avoids any convolution or pooling operations that combine information across individuals until an operation that collapses each column of the (filtered) alignment matrix down to a single value in an order-invariant manner (e.g., site-wise maximum).

Although I understand the concept of this paper. I am having a hard time coding for it using Keras in Python.

Can someone help me get started with it. Had it been a traditional neural network I would've done a 2D convolution on binary matrix and given my vector to a fully connected neural network and then merge these two networks.

But I don't know how to get started with this exchangeable neural network. Help would be appreciated.